# Handling Kernel quit

Tags: evaluation, kernel, system

One can use `$Epilog` to do something when the Kernel is quit or put an `end.m` file next to the `init.m`.

> For Wolfram System sessions, `$Epilog` is conventionally defined to read in a file named end.m.

But if `$Epilog` is set by the user, then `end.m` is skipped.

**Question:** So what to do if I want something to be done each time Kernel is quit but I also want to be able to play with `$Epilog`. In that sense that if I set `$Epilog`  I would like my default action to be taken anyway?

I need to stress out that I want to establish an action that will not be accidentally overwritten with daily (but advanced) mma usage.

Comment: Hackety-hack: could you define an upvalue on `SetDelayed[$Epilog,f_]` such that you append the calling of your `end.m` to the execution of `f`?

Comment: @MartinBüttner it's worth considering that. I need  to stress out  that I wan't to establish an action on quit that will not be accidentally overwritten with daily (but advanced) mma usage. So your solution is quite stable except the fact I have to include it in `init.m`.

Comment: I'd post it as an answer, but thinking about it I'm actually not quite sure how I'd call the unmodified `SetDelayed` inside the upvalue definition (so as not to run into infinite recursion). I'm sure it's possible, but I'm not that familiar with upvalues.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104403/12  I have no robust solution for cleaning up on exit *and* playing nice with any other software that messes with `$Epilog` or `end.m`.  I gave up on this.

Comment: I asked about it on W Community: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/824185

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to rely on undocumented behavior you can move `$Epilog` out of the System context, and give it a definition that evaluates both an internal (default) expression as well as the public expression assigned to `` System`$Epilog ``.

Your specialized setup:

```
Context[System`$Epilog] = "hidden`";
hidden`$Epilog := (Print["internal"]; System`$Epilog)
```

An arbitrary public definition:

```
$Epilog := Print["external"]
```

Now when the kernel is terminated:

```
Exit[]
```

> ```
> internal
>
> external
> ```

Comment: Why does it work? :) In what conditions Mathematica calls `$Epilog` so it is  found on ``hidden` `` context first?

Comment: @Kuba ``hidden`$Epilog`` is still the internal *Mathematica* function and it is called by low level reference, I assume.  This is no different from moving any other Symbol out of the System context and having it still function when called directly, e.g. you can move `Range` to ``foo`Range`` and when you use ``foo`Range[1, 5]`` it still works.

Comment: Yeah but `$Epilog := Print["external"]` knows you are using ``System` `` because it is on context path, why MMA doesn't know it is there too when it calls `$Epilog` at the end?

Comment: @Kuba I believe the reference is made at a lower level, meaning that the Kernel is not parsing and evaluating a textual input `$Epilog` but instead performing e.g. "operation 3F70BE" which happens to correspond to `$Epilog`.  Contexts are a higher-level abstraction.

Comment: Doing ``Context[StringQ] = "myContext`"`` before loading the documentation center seems to break the documentation center.

Comment: @Jacob Is that a random observation or are you making a point?  If the latter I am not sure what it is.  Surely changing contexts can break a range of things.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sorry, it was a pretty random observation. I think I was just a bit shocked that the technique in your answer is possible and I was trying to make sense of it. You can delete these comments if you want.

Answer (score 5):

In principle this can be done using LibraryLink.  Just run an action on library unload.  The library will be unloaded on kernel exit, if you don't unload it manually before.

**Warning:** This is a heavyweight solution that just won't be practical in most cases.  But it does work and it does not conflict with other packages.  If you need to do the cleanup privately, only on your own computer, then it can be useful.  If you need to do the cleanup from a package that already uses LibraryLink, then it is useful.  Otherwise I wouldn't use it.

For reasons of laziness, here's with LTemplate:

```
<< LTemplate`

tem = LClass["Cleanup", {}];

SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
code = "
  struct Cleanup {
    ~Cleanup() { 
        mma::print(\"C++: Cleaning up\"); 

        // this below calls myCleanupFunction[]
        MLINK link = mma::libData->getMathLink(mma::libData);
        MLPutFunction(link, \"EvaluatePacket\", 1);
            MLPutFunction(link, \"myCleanupFunction\", 0);
        mma::libData->processMathLink(link);
        MLNextPacket(link);
        MLNewPacket(link);
    }
  };
  ";
Export["Cleanup.h", code, "String"];

CompileTemplate[tem, "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print]

LoadTemplate[tem]
```

This will be called on exit:

```
myCleanupFunction[] := Print["Mathematica: Cleaning up"]
```

We create a special object.  When this object is no longer referenced, or when the library is unloaded, the cleanup code will be run.

```
globalCleaner = Make["Cleanup"] 

(* Cleanup[1] *)
```

Now we quit:

```
Quit
```

Quitting triggers unloading the library and this gets printed:

```
C++: Cleaning up

Mathematica: Cleaning up
```

Standard LibraryLink is a bit different than LTemplate.  You'll need to put the code form the destructor above into `WolframLibrary_uninitialize()` and there's no need a create a special object like `Cleanup[1]`.  I have not tested it (again: laziness), but I expect it will work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Add the default epilog code to your own.  This is what the default does.

```
?? $Epilog
```

> ```
> $Epilog:=If[FindFile[end`]=!=$Failed,<<end`]
> ```

Comment: The point is, I want to set an action in end.m or any other way and I don't want to care about that. Using composition each time is not an option, unless we use a trick suggested by Martin in the comment.