# What does the "AutomaticDelete" option for LibraryFunctionLoad do?

Tags: undocumented, librarylink

Apparently, [`LibraryFunctionLoad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html) has an option `"AutomaticDelete"` with default setting `Automatic`.  The documentation page is silent about how this works.  Can I use this to clean up temporary files (as asked in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104403/2048))?  How does this option work in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making my comments into an answer,

> Setting `"AutomaticDelete" -> True` will cause the DLL file to be deleted when the library is unloaded.
>
> At the moment the default setting of `Automatic` means `False`, except when called internally for a `Compile`-generated DLL.

Comment: "At the moment the default setting of `Automatic` means `False`" If that were ever changed to `True`, it would destroy packages that came with precompiled libraries.

Comment: I don't think it would ever change to a global `True`, but as with any `Automatic` setting, the precise meaning could evolve a bit.

Comment: Actually, I'm a bit puzzled why `LibraryFunctionLoad` was given this option instead of `LibraryLoad`.  What happens if I load two different functions from the same library with `LibraryFunctionLoad` with separate settings to `"LibraryFunctionLoad"`?